# Web3 Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js

Im fairly new to using Web3.

I am trying to test out a function that makes purchases for smart contracts (ERC20 coins). I have tested this code to send Ether from one wallet to another and it succeeded. Now i get this error whenever i try to interact with a smart contract (send a signed transactions to purchase coin) :

**Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:**

And this is how it appears on etherscan rinkeby

[image]

**This is my code**

```
  var rawTx = {
    nonce : nxn,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('3000', 'gwei')),
    gasLimit: '0x5208',
    to: '0x40d3b2f06f198d2b789b823cdbecd1db78090d74',
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.002', "ether")),
    data : '0x',
    
  }

  var tx = new Tx(rawTx,{chain:'rinkeby', hardfork: 'petersburg'});
  tx.sign(privateKey);

  var serializedTx = tx.serialize();


  await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
  .on('receipt', console.log);
```

Comment: It means smart contract did `revert()` for your transaction, usually by failing ` require()` line.

Answer (score 6):

It means smart contract did `revert()` for your transaction, usually by failing  `require()` line. Other reasons include trying to make a payable transaction to a smart contract that does not accept payments.

Without the smart contract source code it is not possible to tell what causes the revert.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing the Dapp University Tutorial i think the problem is in the contract with the initialSupply. See if the constructor takes any parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It may occur due to the latest version of web3, try using the **web3@1.8.1** version.